# Calling a view from another view in MVC .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view called `LoggedIn.cshtml` getting called from `LoggedInController`.
Inside the `LoggedInView` I have a PartialView called _`LoggedInPartial` to display the `nav` bar containing different menus like Home, Profile, etc.

I want to call another view `LoggedInHomeView` `onClick` of the home menu of the `nav` bar which is present inside `LoggedInView`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `@Html.Partial("ViewName")`?

Comment: You need javascript to respond to client side events, and ajax to call a server method that returns the partial view your want to add to the DOM

Comment: well the first thing is how will i call a view from another view? And the view I want to call isn't a partial view either..

Comment: You can call a view using RenderAction    @{Html.RenderAction("View", "Controller");}

Comment: Tried that but the problem is _Layout page will get called two times therefore repeating the common styles...

Comment: what does *want to call another view* mean? do you want to redirect to that page? Also, do not add tags which are not related. *entiity-framework* tag has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect to that page. And Sorry!! for that Entity FrameworkTag

Comment: In your `_LoggedInPartial` view you should generates links using `@Html.ActionLink()`. Then you will be automatically redirected to pages when you click on links.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink is an alternate for <a> tag isn't it???

Comment: Anyway @Html.ActionLink is not working...

Answer (score 2):

Say you have view called *LoggedIn.cshtml*, in your view you render partial view called *_LoggedInPartial* like:

```
{ Html.RenderPartial("_LoggedInPartial"); }
```

Generally, if *_LoggedInPartial* is used for navigation inside this view, links are rendered like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Title", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("AnotherTitle", "AnotherActionName", "AnotherControllerName")
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, when you click on links you should be redirected to desired action, and it will render view for you.

Comment: Well,my view is getting rendered using RenderAction, but the problem is _Layout.cshtml is rendered multiple number of times

Comment: please try using below code in '_LoggedInPartial'.

@{
    Layout = null;
}

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("View", "Controller");}
```